# 3-way switches wiring

Tags: wiring

I am wiring a new 3-way switch to coincide with an existing older 3-way switch. The old has 2 seperate traveler wires, but there is only 1 terminal for the traveler on the new switch. I tried combining the 2 travelers with a pigtail to the new switch. Doing this, the new switch works but the older one does not. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you really bought a 3 way switch?

Comment: Add a pic of the new switch.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What you bought is not a 3-way switch...

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the existing boxes please?

Comment: In what way will the new switch "coincide" with the old switch? Do you mean you're replacing one of the switches? If so, why - what symptoms existed that are causing you to take this action? The word "coincide" just doesn't make sense to me in this context.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you aren't trying to replace a 4-way switch with a 3-way switch.  The different types of switches are depicted in the image below.  From left to right:

[image: Types of switches]

Ignore the double-pole switch on the far right.  That switch is not used for 120V switching.

Additionally: the 3-way/4-way terminology is appropriate for the US.  I believe in the UK and Europe, they call what we call a 3-way a 2-way, and a 4-way a 3-way, etc.

Comment: **Both** brass screws on a 3-way **are travelers.** The black on one end is unswitched hot in, and the black on the other end is switched hot out to the light.  It does not have "one traveler." Of course, since the OP has not shown us the switches, it's quite possible you are right about needing a 4 way and they are confused about "what's a traveler" as well.

Comment: @Ecnerwal You are correct.  I cleaned up my answer to make it more clear.  Until we see the original switch, all we can do is define what might be there.